# jquery animate is toggling the div at the top very slowly

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-animate

I am using the animate function of jQuery to slide the div to top and then back to its position. It is working but sliding the div very slowly. I am using the speed to fast and even tried millisecond option.

```
var result = isScrolledIntoView("header");
if(!result){
   $("#div").animate({top:"160px"},"100");
}
```

checking if header is not visible

```
function isScrolledIntoView(elem)
{
  var docViewTop = $(window).scrollTop();
  var docViewBottom = docViewTop + $(window).height();

  var elemTop = $(elem).offset().top;
  var elemBottom = elemTop + $(elem).height();

  return ((elemBottom <= docViewBottom) && (elemTop >= docViewTop));
}
```

so I have header and then this div. So when user scroll header up, then we get space above this div. so i am checking if user scroll up the header then give this div top css.. which is working but its very slow. I want to slide up as soon as header is not visible.

Comment: You should show us the code where you check for scrolling down. Since the scroll event is likely to be executed very often, several animations may overlap.

Comment: How does your HTML look like? Please share a minified version of your code for testing. I think it will be easier to use css classes instead of a fixed value from jquery script.